# Python- Basemap error when installing data-hires

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, matplotlib-basemap

Hello I'm installing basemap at anaconda 3.

I had the problem with the "PROJ_LIB" path but I have already solved it.
The problem is when I try to install the data-hires with:

```
conda install basemap-data-hires
```

Everything goes well but at the end this message appears:

```
InvalidArchiveError('Error with archive C:\\Users\\Ann\\anaconda3\\pkgs\\openssl-1.1.1d-he774522_4ahmj82pg\\pkg-openssl-1.1.1d-he774522_4.tar.zst.  You probably need to delete and re-download or re-create this file.  Message from libarchive was:\n\nCould not unlink')
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Did you install anything else before this? Can you share the output of `conda list` ? _I had the problem with the "PROJ_LIB" path_ What is that?

Comment: It's is because it can't find the "epsg" file. You need to look for it, and the path that comes out, you need to paste it in the "__init__.py" file, it comes out in "PROJ_LIB" error,paste the path in the "pyproj_datadir" variable. That should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I did is to erase all of the `openssl-1.1.1` files, close the terminal and spyder and re open it.

After that I re-install Basemap, and then I install the data-hires with:

```
conda install -c conda-forge basemap-data-hires
```

Once I did that everything work well.